# php syntax - why does making my code a function stop it working?

Tags: php

Probably a simple one so please excuse me.

At the top of my page I include a file:

```
<?
    require("common.php");
    ?>
```

Later on in my code I do the following:

```
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

(the db connection files being in my include file).

This works fine, until I try and make the code a function For example: If I do

```
    function doAQuery(){
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $result = $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

It can't find the db details. Please can someone explain why?

Comment: There is no `$query` available in your function. (And PHP would have told you that, if you only had set your error reporting to a sensible value – so please go do that _now_!) [Basics, Baby!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Because `$db` is not in the scope of your function. Use `global` or make a DB class that does this for you while keeping `$db` as a local class variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a syntax issue. Your `$db` and `$query` variables are not available to your function scope. You can make them available by declaring `global $db, $query` as the first line of your function.

Comment: This is horrible practice, you should be using dependency injection.

Comment: the question asked why it doesn't work?, not how can I be a better programer?

Comment: I agree with Tim, he answered the question correctly. Of course there are better design patterns than this, but that's a way more broader question.

Comment: I am of course interested in best practice for this. Any advice will be taken gratefully.

Comment: @Programatt see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/1592648 don't use `global` use dependency injection instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `$db` is a global variable. PHP ignores it in the function scope unless you explicity declare it should be used.

```
function doAQuery() {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Take a look at how [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php) works in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Query string to function,

```
function doAQuery($query){
```

Comment: Please read the question.